# How to remotely debug ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

I want to find out which method/command in ActiveMQ gets called when we send message to ActiveMQ. 
This i want to find out by remotely debugging ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 0):

see the activeMQ documentation to debug the broker : http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-debug-activemq-from-my-ide.html

> One option is to run your broker in the same JVM as your application;
>   see [How to unit test JMS code](http://activemq.apache.org/how-to-unit-test-jms-code.html). 
>   Or you can try uncommenting
>   ACTIVEMQ_DEBUG_OPTS in your activemq start script (bin/activemq or
>   bin\activemq.bat) and start remote debugging in your IDE. 
>   For IDEA, see this article
>   http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200408/DebuggingServer-sideCode.html